# Why is a pointer to pointer treated differently than a pointer in spite of corresponding corrections

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I'm trying to delete a Node from a Doubly Linked List. The function deleteNode() will receive the head of the linked list and the node to be deleted. However, depending on whether I pass the node to be deleted as a pointer or a pointer to pointer, the code behaves differently (in spite of making the corresponding corrections in syntax).

Here is my structure for Doubly Linked List node -

```
struct DNode {
int val;
struct DNode* next;
struct DNode* prev;
DNode(int val) { //constructor
    this->val = val;
    next = NULL;
    prev = NULL;
}
};
```

The following code works perfectly fine:

```
void deleteNode(struct DNode** head, struct DNode* deleteMe) {
//head is pointer to pointer, deleteMe is pointer

if(!(*head) || !deleteMe) {
    cout<<"\nDeletion not possible";
    return;
}

if(deleteMe->prev != NULL)
    deleteMe->prev->next = deleteMe->next;

if(deleteMe->next != NULL)
    deleteMe->next->prev = deleteMe->prev;

if(deleteMe == *head)
    *head = deleteMe->next;

delete deleteMe;
}
```

Correspoding Driver Code -

```
/*at this point, I have pushed elements into the Linked List to make it 4->3->2->1, where 4 is 
the head*/
deleteNode(&head, head);      
deleteNode(&head, head->next); 
deleteNode(&head, head->next);
```

However, when I send both parameters as pointer to pointer, I experience a crash at runtime:

```
void deleteNode(struct DNode** head, struct DNode** deleteMe) {

if(!(*head) || !(*deleteMe)) {
    cout<<"\nDeletion not possible";
    return;
}

if((*deleteMe)->prev != NULL)
    (*deleteMe)->prev->next = (*deleteMe)->next;

if((*deleteMe)->next != NULL)
    (*deleteMe)->next->prev = (*deleteMe)->prev;

if(*deleteMe == *head)
    *head = (*deleteMe)->next;

delete *deleteMe;
}
```

Corresponding driver code:

```
/*at this point, I have pushed elements into the Linked List to make it 4->3->2->1, where 4 is 
the head*/
deleteNode(&head, &head);      
deleteNode(&head, &head->next);
deleteNode(&head, &head->next);
```

**PS - this is not entirely an issue with delete:**

if you comment the line delete *deleteMe in the erroneous code, the code will run but the output will be different.

Output for working code: 3

Output for erroneous code after commenting the delete line: 3->1

Comment: Instead of a comment telling us what `head` is, show it in code. Make a [mre].

Comment: In the first case, the second argument is passed by value.   So (inside the function) changes of `*head` cannot interact with changes (to the object pointed to) by `deleteMe`.   Passing the second argument as a pointer to pointer means that (inside) the function `*head` and `*deleteMe` (or `(*deleteMe)->next` or `(*deleteMe)->prev`) may be the same objects.  That difference of interaction between the arguments explains the difference of behaviour.  Giving the variables in `main()` and the variables or arguments in `deleteNode()` different names might make the interaction more obvious visually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, when you pass `&head` and `&head`,

```
if(*deleteMe == *head)
    *head = (*deleteMe)->next;
```

`*deleteMe` and `*head` are the same object (the object whose address you passed in), and they are still the same object after the assignment.
(That is, it is equivalent to both `*head = (*head)->next;` and `*deleteMe = (*deleteMe)->next`.)

So this,

```
delete *deleteMe;
```

does the same as `delete *head` in this case, and then things go boom.

In the first case, `*head` and `deleteMe` are different objects, so assigning to `*head` does not affect `deleteMe`.

As an illustration, this is what happens ("main_head" is the variable in `main`).

When you enter the function, you have this situation:

```
  head
   |
   v          +---+   +---+
main_head---->|  ---->| ----> ...
   ^          +---+   +---+
   |                    ^
 deleteMe               |
                  (*deleteMe)->next
```

And after the assignment `*head = (*deleteMe)->next`:

```
  head    +-------------+
   |      |             |
   |      |             v
   v      |   +---+   +---+
main_head-+   |  ---->| ----> ...
   ^          +---+   +---+
   |
 deleteMe
```

And you can see that `head` and `deleteMe` still point to `main`'s `head`, and that is the object you assigned a value to.

With the working code, you start with this:

```
  head        
   |           
   v          +---+   +---+
main_head---->|  ---->| ----> ...
              +---+   +---+
                ^       ^
                |       |
            deleteMe   deleteMe->next
```

And end up with

```
  head    +-------------+
   |      |             |
   |      |             v
   v      |   +---+   +---+
main_head-+   |  ---->| ----> ...
              +---+   +---+
                ^       ^
                |       |
            deleteMe   deleteMe->next
```

Comment: Hold up. When you say "they are still the same object after the assignment", how is that possible? The way I see it, when I pass &head and &head, then (in the function) *head and *delete are aliases for the same node in the beginning. When I say `*head = (*deleteMe)->next;` , *head now points to the 2nd node in the linked list while *deleteMe still points to the first node. So `delete *deleteMe;` can't possibly mean the same as `delete *head;`

Comment: Yes, `*head` and `*deleteMe` are "aliases" to the same object. Thus, when you assign to `*head`, that affects `*deleteMe`, since it is the same thing. I will add a little ASCII art to illustrate.

Comment: bro that ASCII art was super helpful, thanks I get it now